# I want to sum sales of similar country

Tags: r, dplyr

I have this data in a spreadsheet

```
Country       Sales
Spain 1       1000
Spain 2       200
France        300
Nigeria 1     500
Nigeria 2     700
```

I want the sum of this country's sales stored a seperate dataframe.

I tried using the dplyr function but the result is not what i want

Here is the output I want please

```
Country   Sum_of_sales

Spain     1200
France    300
Nigeria   1200
```

Is there a way I can run this on R that will give me this above output stored in a separate dataframe please.

Comment: Please don't use the [rstudio] tag unless the problem is RStudio specific, for example if you have R code that works on the R command line or R GUI, but doesn't work in RStudio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wanna keep it `tidyverse`, you can use `extract`:

```r
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  extract(Country, "Country") %>% 
  group_by(Country) %>% 
  summarise(Sum_of_sales = sum(Sales))

# A tibble: 3 × 2
  Country Sum_of_sales
  <chr>          <int>
1 France           300
2 Nigeria         1200
3 Spain           1200
```

For more complex cases, you can use:

```r
extract(Country, "Country", "([A-Za-z -]*)\\s*[0-9]*")
```

Comment: Warning that this won't work as written if you have countries with spaces in the names. Though `extract` is cool new function to me!

Answer (score 2):

Strip the trailing numbers (and spaces) off the country labels, then do a normal grouped sum:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  mutate(Country= gsub(pattern = " *[0-9]+", replacement = "", x = Country)) %>%
  group_by(Country) %>%
  summarize(Sum_of_Sales = sum(Sales))
# # A tibble: 3 × 2
#   Country Sum_of_Sales
#   <chr>          <int>
# 1 France           300
# 2 Nigeria         1200
# 3 Spain           1200
```

---

Using this sample input:

```
df = read.table(text = "Country       Sales
'Spain 1'       1000
'Spain 2'       200
'France'        300
'Nigeria 1'     500
'Nigeria 2'     700", header = T)
```

Comment: Thank you, Gregor. Is a way I can group the sales of France and Spain as one called Europe? Thank you again

Comment: Like this Country   Sum_of_sales

Europe   1500
Nigeria   1200

Comment: Sure, but you'll need some sort of reference to group them. If you want to manually code that Spain and France are in Europe, sure, but more likely you want to find or create a data frame with a Country column and a Region column and then `left_join()` it to your data.

Comment: For hand-coding: `df %>% mutate(Country= gsub(pattern = " *[0-9]+", replacement = "", x = Country), Region = ifelse(Country %in% c("Spain", "France"), "Europe", Country)) %>% ....` (the rest is the same as above).

Comment: Thanks Gregor. I just followed your instruction and it seem not to group France and Spain as Europe. Please check the code. Thanks. Turnover_Difference %>% mutate(Country= gsub(pattern = " *[0-9]+", replacement = "", x = Country), Region = ifelse(Country %in% c("France", "Spain"), "Europe", Country)) %>% group_by(Country) %>% summarize(Sum_of_sales = sum(sales))

Comment: You'll need to `group_by(Region)` not country.

Comment: Thank you, Gregor. You are a lifesaver. Just one thing, please. While Austria 1 and Austria 2 converted to Austria and summed their sales, I just discovered that my Germany 1 and Germany 2 just converted to Germany each but did not sum their sales. Please I would appreciate your help once again

Comment: I can't tell why that wouldn't work from your description. You should edit your question to include data that shows the Germany problem. Or try Mael's answer, maybe it works.

Answer (score 0):

An option with `str_remove`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df %>% 
  group_by(Country = str_remove(Country, "\\s+\\d+")) %>% 
  summarise(Sum_of_sales = sum(Sales))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 3 × 2
  Country Sum_of_sales
  <chr>          <int>
1 France           300
2 Nigeria         1200
3 Spain           1200
```